# how to fix "settings has stopped" error

Tags: lg

I was  uninstalling  some bloatware on my lg l15g and now can't access my settings.  Get an error message of settings has stopped. What is responsible for this?

Comment: Hard to pin down. Log the action using [tag:logcat] and give us the output.

Comment: What are bloatware's you uninstalled? Name them?
As @Firelord asked you, give us some clues, logcat traces will be good.

Answer (score 0):

On my LG L16C (Kitkat 4.4.2) I had that issue several times. I bought the phone only two months ago and realized that certain aftermarket apps were causing the problem-each time my settings froze, removal of newly added apps (one at a time, testing after each) stopped the problem...just added similar apps instead.